# Is there a way to realloc memory for an array to allow adding additional values to the beginning?

Tags: c, arrays, padding, realloc

I need to pad the beginning of an existing array with zeros. My current method is to reallocate additional memory for the array, shift every value forward, and then add the zeros.

This is very slow for very large arrays, so I was wondering if there is a method in C to re-allocate memory for the beginning of the array?

For example, if the original size of the array n1=100, and I want to add npad=10 values, is there a way to reallocate such that the array[i] now points to the value previously stored at array[i-npad]?

Not hopeful, but thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that's possible using malloc/realloc/free. Perhaps using a platform specific function?

Comment: instead of `shift every value forward`, you could use [memmove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k35d1fx.aspx) to move the whole memory block

Comment: Where does the array come from?  Often, if such functionality is required, the array gets loaded at some fixed offset and then there is space underneath it to 'add' zeros and pointer-arthmetic the start addr of the zeros.

Comment: @Martin - not a solution for all instances, but actually quite a god tip. Hadn't thought of that!

Comment: @Edward, this may be the solution in cases where I cannot know the amount of data I'm reading in advance. Is there any benchmarking to show whether memmove() is more efficient than copying the data forward from the last value to the first? As this does not require copying to a buffer first.

Comment: I don't have the data at hand, but `memmove()` should definitely be faster than moving each item -- see the code snippet in my answer

Answer (score 3):

What you are requesting is not only not supported by the standard C library but is impossible in theory, except by allocating the potentially needed space at the time of the initial allocation. A routine could give you the illusion of adding space to the beginning in the way that `realloc` gives the illusion of adding space to the end, but this requires (potentially) moving the data, regardless of whether you do it yourself or have the called routine do it.

For comparison, `realloc` does not guarantee that it will allocate more space on the end of an array. It might try to allocate more space on the end of an array, but all it guarantees is that it will provide the same data in a larger space, if the space is available. To do this, if it cannot enlarge the existing allocation, it allocates new space and **moves the data**.

If we attempt to implement a routine that increases an allocation at its beginning, we are faced with a choice at the time of the initial allocation:

- Allocate whatever space is available. In this case, the space might be just after other allocated space.
- Allocate space with padding of unused space before it.

If we choose the former, the allocation cannot be enlarged at its beginning. If we choose the latter, we are wasting space and must know in advance how much space will be required.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like

```
char *GrowArrayAtEnd(char *pOldArray, int nOldSize, int nNewSize)
{   char *pNewArray = (char *)realloc(pOldArray, nNewSize);
    memmove(&pNewArray[nNewSize - nOldSize], pNewArray, nOldSize);
    memset(pNewArray, 0, nNewSize - nOldSize); // if necessary
    return pNewArray;
}
```